# Run redis-cli commands as a cron job

Tags: redis, scheduled-tasks, cron

How can i run the following redis-cli command using a cron job?

```
redis-cli info clients
```

I wrote a simple bash script with this command, and setup a cron job to run every minute. But it does not seem like redis-cli commands are working with crontab.

Any suggestion how i can achieve this?

Comment: You are probably missing the full path to the command, maybe `/usr/local/bin/redis-cli` or some such. Presumably you want to send the output somewhere too... use `> someFile.txt` at the and of the command.

Comment: I am using the full path, and also redirecting the stdout and sdterr to a file. But it says command not found. However, i have manually tested the command directly in the terminal and it works just fine

Comment: Please click `edit` underneath your question and show what you are actually doing. At the Terminal, try `which redis-cli` to see the correct path.

Comment: What is the expected output\behaviour? Do you check in your `/etc/syslog` if is there something?

Answer (score 1):

As posted by [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell) in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33626034/run-redis-cli-commands-as-a-cron-job/72372797#comment55028861_33626034)

> You are probably missing the full path to the command, maybe `/usr/local/bin/redis-cli` or some such. Presumably you want to send the output somewhere too... use `> someFile.txt` at the and of the command.

referring to the full path of redis-cli worked for me.

Comment: The answer option is only for solution. If you faced the same problem and an answer was helpful, consider to upvote that answer. However, do not use the answer option to state that. SO is not a forum in the ordinary sense where answers are used to communicate with each other.